# How to limit execution time in bigquery client query using python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to run a BQ query using python which sometimes take around 6 hours to complete the execution. I would like to limit this execution time to 2 hours. That means even if the query does not complete its execution in that 2 hours, it should stop running with status "failed". And off course it is good if execution complete within 2 hours.

code under utility.py :

```
def execute_select_bq_query(query, location, jobconfig):
    from google.cloud import bigquery

    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client(project=queryexcproject)
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    dest_table = bq_table_reference(client, jobconfig['destination'])
    job_config.destination = dest_table
    job_config.create_disposition = jobconfig['create_disposition']
    job_config.write_disposition = jobconfig['write_disposition']
    query_job = client.query(query, location=location, job_config=job_config)
    results = query_job.result()
    response = "Data loaded into BQ table {}".format(jobconfig['destination'])
    return response
```

BQ job configuration under main.py :

```
from utility import execute_select_bq_query

def get_data(request):

    job_config = {"destination": bq_project_details,
                          "create_disposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
                          "write_disposition": tbl_write_disposition}
    response = execute_select_bq_query(query, bq_location, job_config)
    print(response)

    return response()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timeout in the `query_job.result()` function :

```py
def execute_select_bq_query(query, location, jobconfig):
    from google.cloud import bigquery
    
    # Timeout in seconds (float)
    timeout = 

    # Construct a BigQuery client object.
    client = bigquery.Client(project=queryexcproject)
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    dest_table = bq_table_reference(client, jobconfig['destination'])
    job_config.destination = dest_table
    job_config.create_disposition = jobconfig['create_disposition']
    job_config.write_disposition = jobconfig['write_disposition']
    query_job = client.query(query, location=location, job_config=job_config)
    results = query_job.result(
           timeout=timeout,
           job_retry=None
    )
    response = "Data loaded into BQ table {}".format(jobconfig['destination'])
    return response
```

The documentation says :

```
timeout (Optional[float]):
                The number of seconds to wait for the underlying HTTP transport
                before using ``retry``.
                If multiple requests are made under the hood, ``timeout``
                applies to each individual request.

job_retry (Optional[google.api_core.retry.Retry]):
                How to retry failed jobs.  The default retries
                rate-limit-exceeded errors. Passing ``None`` disables
                job retry.

                Not all jobs can be retried.  If ``job_id`` was
                provided to the query that created this job, then the
                job returned by the query will not be retryable, and
                an exception will be raised if non-``None``
                non-default ``job_retry`` is also provided.
```

To limit the execution time of your query, you have to pass the `timeout` param and if you don't want to execute a job retry you can pass the `job_retry` param as `None`.

Comment: Tosum, I want to add limit at query timeout, i.e. the maximum time to wait for the query to complete. The query timeout is used by the blocking poll so that the backend does not block for too long when polling for job completion.

In the solution provided by you we are passing timeout at transport layer.